# Add new item to list with lookup value from another list via powershell

Tags: powershell

I have trying to add new item via powershell to a list that has a column with a lookup to another list

```
    $NewItem = $list.Items.Add()

    #Add properties to this list item
    $NewItem["Title"] = "$($Title)"
    $NewItem["Connections"] = "Connection1"

    #Update the object so it gets saved to the list
    $NewItem.Update()
```

But l keep getting "Invalid look-up value" The "Connections" is the column that had a lookup value to the connections list

Not sure how to reference the lookup value called "Connection1"

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out if anyone wants to know.

I needed a reference to the ID of the item:

```
$listLookupitem = $ListLookup.GetItemById(4)

$NewItem["Connection"] = [string]$listLookupitem.ID + ";#" + $listLookupitem.Title
```